# How to do $state.go() with params?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have perfectly initialized $stateProvider and I'm using all this states with ui-sref. Works great. 
User presses the button and thorugh the $stateProvider goes to the edit page.

On this page I have a form which does $http request:

```
 this.pushData = function (data) {
        $http.post('/data/' + $stateParams.dataId + '/otherdata', JSON.stringify({
            id: otherdata.id, 
            name: otherdata.name
        }), configAuth).then(
            function success(response) {
                var addedData = response.data;
                $.notify({message: addedData.name + " has been added"},{type:'success'});

                $state.go('roleInfo({roleId: $stateParams.roleId})');
            },
            function error(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $.notify({message: data.data.message},{type:'danger'});
            }
        );

    }
```

And I want to do redirect to other view if everything is fine. But this:

> $state.go('roleInfo({roleId: $stateParams.roleId})');

doesn't work. How can I do $state.go with params?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are trying that would work with `ui-sref` directive, while calling it using `$state.go` method, you should pass 1st parameter is `stateName` & then pass params in `Object` format.

```
$state.go('roleInfo', {roleId: $stateParams.roleId});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`$state.go('myStateName', {roleId: $stateParams.roleId});`

[You can read the docs here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

Answer (score 2):

i have changed 
`$state.go('roleInfo({roleId: $stateParams.roleId})');` to

```
 $state.go('roleInfo',{roleId :$stateParams.roleId});
```

this will work

---

```
this.pushData = function (data) {
            $http.post('/data/' + $stateParams.dataId + '/otherdata', JSON.stringify({
                id: otherdata.id, 
                name: otherdata.name
            }), configAuth).then(
                function success(response) {
                    var addedData = response.data;
                    $.notify({message: addedData.name + " has been added"},{type:'success'});

                   $state.go('roleInfo',{roleId :$stateParams.roleId});                    },
                function error(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.notify({message: data.data.message},{type:'danger'});
                }
            );

        }
```